# Why wordpress sites top -c showing that only index file is used

Tags: wordpress, process, top

I am want to that Why wordpress sites `top -c` showing that only index file is used.

**What all request are handle by index.php?**

when every time i check `top -c` it's show as below:

```
743204 (Trace) (Kill)   affinity    0     4.34  0.14    /usr/bin/php /home/affinity/public_html/index.php
743251 (Trace) (Kill)   sdoifn3m2   0     4.01  0.12    /usr/bin/php /home/sdoifn3m2/public_html/index.php
743228 (Trace) (Kill)   noidaads    0     3.96  0.12    /usr/bin/php /home/noidaads/public_html/index.php
743323 (Trace) (Kill)   hotelhil    0     2.39  0.07    /usr/bin/php /home/hotelhil/public_html/index.php
742994 (Trace) (Kill)   xtremeit    0     2.26  0.13    /usr/bin/php /home/xtremeit/public_html/index.php
743013 (Trace) (Kill)   xtremeit    0     2.19  0.12    /usr/bin/php /home/xtremeit/public_html/index.php
742914 (Trace) (Kill)   mjtouchc    0     1.43  0.10    /usr/bin/php /home/mjtouchc/public_html/index.php
742373 (Trace) (Kill)   mjtouchc    0     1.36  0.14    /usr/bin/php /home/mjtouchc/public_html/index.php
743278 (Trace) (Kill)   ypages99    0     1.20  0.18    /usr/bin/php /home/ypages99/public_html/index.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress works by only loading one `index.php` with additional request parameters that control which database entries are displayed in the browser.

I don't have a wordpress install at hand so the parameters are likely different, but it works largely like that:

```
http://example.org/wp/index.php?id=222
```

would tell Wordpress to load the blog entry with the internal id 222 and display it.

Comment: In addition requests for static content are handled directly by the webserver and won't show as identifiable processes belonging to a specific user/site in `top`